# Is it possible to uniquely identify a USB disk clone that boots on linux computer as NOT the original

Tags: linux, usb, unique, identify

The following is the case and question:
I have a linux installation on a 128GB sandisk.
When I clone the disk on another 128GB sandisk the UUID stays the same.
My first thoughts to detect a clone was to check the UUID but that clearly does not work.

So my question is: How can I detect that the cloned USB is actually a clone?
Is there any way to uniquely identify the USB disk device itself given that your booting from it and not inserting it in the USB port of another linux system?

Comment: The physical drive should have a distinct serial number. If you save it on the original then it won't match on the copy.

Comment: Thats what I though.
However, after doing a dd of the USB (org) to another USB (clone), when booting of either USBdisk and checking with the command blkid, I get the same UUID.

After booting with the clone (created with dd) I want to be able to detect that I am not in the original. So naturaly I though of UUID. But the UUID is the same because it is a dd copy. The UUID was created during the creation of the diskstructure when the installation was done.

Is there a way to detect that I have started a clone (dd copy) and that I am not in the original USBdisk?